# Setting up mock objects for EF dbcontext to test repository methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have entityframework repo which gets trip information from sqldb. I have created the repo and on constructor injecting the dbContext and using that context doing database operation.

```
 public class WorldRepository : IWorldRepository
    {
        private WorldContext _context;

        public WorldRepository(WorldContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void AddSop(string tripName, Stop newStop)
        {
            var trip = GetTipByName(tripName);

            if (trip != null)
            {
                trip.Stops.Add(newStop);
                _context.Stops.Add(newStop);
            }
        }

        public void AddTrip(Trip trip)
        {
            _context.Add(trip);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Trip> GetAllTrips()
        {
            return _context.Trips.ToList();
        }
}
```

Now I am trying to test using MOQ, but this does not help . I am not able to test any of logic writen on my methods as it's querying mock object and not my implementation.

```
  // private Mock<IWorldRepository> _mockWorld;

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_AddTrips()
        {
            //Arrange
            // WorldRepository repo = new WorldRepository(null);

            Mock<IWorldRepository> _mockWorld = new Mock<IWorldRepository>();
            var repo = _mockWorld.Object;

            //Act
            repo.AddSop("Sydney", new Stop
            {
                Arrival = DateTime.Now,
                Id = 2,
                Latittude = 0.01,
                Longitude = 0.005,
                Name = "Test Trip",
                Order = 5
            });

            repo.SaveChangesAsync();

            var count = repo.GetAllTrips().Count();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(1, count);


        }
```

This is code for WorldContext.

```
public class WorldContext:DbContext
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;

        public WorldContext(IConfigurationRoot config,DbContextOptions options)
            :base(options)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stop> Stops{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:WorldCotextConnection"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use WorldRepository class and mock dbcontext .Could you post the code for WorldContext  as well.

Comment: You should probably be mocking WorldContext, and passing that into WorldRepository.

Comment: Microsoft provided an implementation for an async mock. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to mock `WorldContextand` to use it with your repo instance ,so we need to mock that first. To do that create an interface for `worlddbcontext`.

```
public interface IWorldContext
    {
        DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
        DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    }
```

Now what you want is to mock the dependencies and the test the subject.

In this case you want to mock `WorldDbContext` , mock the  `DbSet<Stop>` and  test AddSop method.

To create a mock DbSet, I am refering to [MSDN, EF Testing with Mocking framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) as also mentioned by *Jasen* in the comments.

```
 private Mock<IWorldContext> _context;
 private WorldRepository _repo;

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_AddTrips()
        {
            ////Arrange          

            var data = new List<Stop> {
                 new Stop
                {
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15),
                    Id = 1,
                    Latittude = 0.05,
                    Longitude = 0.004,
                    Name = "Test Trip01",
                    Order = 1
                },
                   new Stop
                {
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20),
                    Id = 2,
                    Latittude = 0.07,
                    Longitude = 0.015,
                    Name = "Test Trip02",
                    Order = 2
                }

            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Stop>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stop>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stop>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stop>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stop>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns( data.GetEnumerator());


            _context = new Mock<IWorldContext>();

           //Set the context of mock object to  the data we created.
            _context.Setup(c => c.Stops).Returns(mockSet.Object);

           //Create instance of WorldRepository by injecting mock DbContext we created
            _repo = new WorldRepository(_context.Object);    


            //Act
            _repo.AddSop("Sydney",
                new Stop
                {
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now,
                    Id = 2,
                    Latittude = 0.01,
                    Longitude = 0.005,
                    Name = "Test Trip",
                    Order = 5
                });

            _repo.SaveChangesAsync();

            var count = _repo.GetAllTrips().Count();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(3, count);


        }
```

Also , there is a brilliant [module](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/full-stack-dot-net-developer-architecture-testing) (just a reference, no endorsement or anything else) on plural sight by [Mosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292120/mosh) on `Testing Repository` module he has explained this in great detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test WorldRepository you need to create real object of this type and mock all it's external dependencies - WorldContext in your case.

So proper setup for your test should be like this:

```
var contextMock = new Mock<WorldContext>();
contextMock.Setup(...); //setup desired behaviour
var repo = new WorldRepository(contextMock.Object);
```